# What video connection gives the highest quality output on a Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I'm about to buy a high definition TV and want to hook my Wii up to it.

What video connection should I use to give the best quality picture?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You want to buy the component cable, which supports the [Wii's maximum output resolution of 480p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii#Technical_specifications).**

480p (DVD-quality) looks *much* better than the 480i (more like pre-DVD, analog TV quality) you get with the (included) composite cable.

It's still not the 720p, 1080i, or 1080p that newer TVs can handle, but the Wii doesn't output in those resolutions.

Comment: Notice you can buy any compatible cable. I personnally bought a non-nintendo cable, for a third of the official cable price, with the same quality benefits.

Answer (score 2):

The [component cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nintendo-Official-Component-Video-Cable/dp/B000JJRV90) lets you use higher resolutions I think, but the Wii does not support true HD yet, unfortunately. I think it looks better than the red/white/yellow cable it came with.

The component cable has to be purchased separately, at least in the UK.

If you do get one, make sure to change the settings in the Wii Menu to take advantage of the new capability.

Answer (score 0):

Component would be the highest level of video quality possible with a Wii and is the best you can get, giving you a crystal clear image. Component sends separate blue and red color data to the TV through the red and blue cables with green being filled in by the unit. Composite combines all the colors into a single cable typically the yellow one and looks awful on an HD TV. The colors can't be separated fully once combined and with the higher resolution the blurry image that results is exacerbated.