# Best way to connect Nintendo Wii with TV

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, monitor

How can I obtain quite good quality of video on an LCD 50" TV with Nintendo Wii. I bought this console a week ago and had in the package two sets of cables - RCA and component. But then I realized that I don't have component input in my TV.
I tried to use Wii with an RCA connection, but doing this was not enjoyable.
I saw on some web stores a lot of cheap converters to HDMI (plugged into Wii directly and have the HDMI socket on the opposite side), but I don't believe in the quality of those solutions.

So, what should I do, to enjoy playing on Wii on this TV? Is there any solution for that, or maybe I should just buy a smaller TV/monitor with component input?

Comment: [Component appears to be the superior connection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/475/what-video-connection-gives-the-highest-quality-output-on-a-wii), so if your TV doesn't support that, then you will need one that does to improve the quality further.  I don't think there is any other option.

Comment: @TimmyJim well, unfortunatelly my TV does not have component socket. I've bought some converter to HDMI dedicated to Wii. Will see how it works and provide some feedback here.